# How to switch to Rear Camera in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone

I can't seem to find the property for the MediaCapture class that allows me to detect the back and front camera in Surface and switch to it if available with Combobox Items. Here is my current setup of the device.

```
        mc = new MediaCapture();
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

        // Use the front camera if found one
        if (devices == null) return;
        var info = devices[0];

        //var rearCamera;
        //DeviceInformation info2 = devices[1];

        foreach (var devInfo in devices)
        {
            if (devInfo.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("front"))
            {

                info = devInfo;
                //info2 = devInfo;
                //frontCam = true;
                //backCam = true;
                camera = true;
                //continue;
            }
            if (devInfo.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("back"))
            {
                var rearCamera = devices[1];
                rearCamera = devInfo;
            }
        }

        await mc.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
            MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Communications,
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo,
            VideoDeviceId = info.Id,
                //VideoDeviceId = info2.Id
            });


        DisplayInformation displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        displayInfo.OrientationChanged += DisplayInfo_OrientationChanged;
        DisplayInfo_OrientationChanged(displayInfo, null);

        stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        llmr = await mc.PrepareLowLagRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto), stream);
        await llmr.StartAsync();
        await llmr.StopAsync();


        CaptureElement.Source = mc;
        CaptureElement.FlowDirection = camera ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        CaptureStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CameraErrorTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        RecordProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CaptureGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CancelButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        //CaptureElement.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

        // prepare low lag recording
        stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        llmr = await mc.PrepareLowLagRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto), stream);



        await mc.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to run MediaCapture.InitializeAsync again with VideoDeviceId of the desired camera device (acquired from DeviceInformationCollection devices). Then set CaptureElement.Source to the new MediaCapture.

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

if (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                if (devices.Count >= 2)
                {
                    var device = devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                }
            }


var frontVideoId = device.Id;
await mc.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
            MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Communications,
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo,
            VideoDeviceId = frontVideoId
            });
CaptureElement.Source = mc;
await mc.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Comment: Can you post a simple example how you think using the above code.

Comment: sample added, EnclosureLocation will tell you the position of camera

Comment: Yes but i want to have a code for both cameras to switch them with Combobx Selected Index.

Comment: The core of this function is in the sample code.. Just get list of camera device info, feed to ComboBox itemssource, on event handler for ComboBox, init the the camera using the code I gave.

Comment: Yes i have tried your Code but the var device = devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front); is decleread inside if(Statment) and when i type outside like this ->var frontVideoId = device.Id; it dosen't recognize device.ID(error) Please also can you give me an Example i how its done with combobx am new to UWP..

Comment: Can you show me an example sir with combobox here is my link to a post where i managed to do something but i didn't archive something. >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526206/how-to-set-a-selected-camer-with-combobx-in-windows-10-universal-app?noredirect=1#comment58743629_35526206

Answer (score 2):

You should use ***"EnclosureLocation"*** property of DeviceInformation.

```
var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
// Get the desired camera by panel
DeviceInformation cameraDevice =
    allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null &&
    x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
```

**Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back** will be the rear camera's EnclosureLocation.

Comment: I have tried this but it is getting always the Front Camera, I want to access also the Back Camera with a Combobox SelectedItem

Comment: You can try to access allVideoDevices to check EnclosureLocation of each DeviceInformation. And about comboBox, you can bind Panels to your comboBox.