# How to "set" a selected camera with combobox in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, win-universal-app

I am developing windows application.I want to switch from Front Camera to Back Camera with a `Combobox` in Windows Universal App or in `WPF`.

I have coded something but I don't get where I made a mistake.

Here is my code:

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="SettingsCamera"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5" SelectionChanged="SettingsCamera_SelectionChanged"/>

private async void InitializeCameraAsync()
        {DeviceInformation device = FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel);



                var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
                SettingsCamera.Items.Clear();
                //_deviceList = new List<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation>();
                // Add the devices to deviceList
                if (devices.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
                    {
                       // _deviceList.Add(devices[i]);
                        SettingsCamera.Items.Add(devices[i].Name);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No camera device is found ");
                }
        }

private async void SettingsCamera_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
            if (SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {

                try
                {
                    var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
                    //SettingsMicrophone.Items.Clear();
                    var frontCamera = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);


                    if (allVideoDevices.Count == 0)
                    {
                        SettingsCamera.Items.Add(frontCamera.Name);
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    //audioExist = false;
                    SettingsCamera.Items.Add("No michrophone on your system");
                }




            }
            else if (SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 1 && SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 2 && SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {

                try
                {
                    var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
                    var backCamera = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                    //SettingsMicrophone.Items.Clear();
                    if (allVideoDevices.Count >=2)
                    {
                        SettingsCamera.Items.Add(backCamera.Name);
                    }
                    SettingsCamera.Items.Add(backCamera.Name);

                    //make first cam default
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    //audioExist = false;
                    SettingsCamera.Items.Add("No michrophone on your system");
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: It is kind of unclear about what your intent is.  Are you wanting to know how to set a property when your selected item changes or change the selected item of your ComboBox programmatically?  Could you please clarify what you mean when you say "set a selected camera with a ComboBox"

Comment: With this code I am populating my Combobox: In this case I get two Cameras one is the Front Camera and the BackCamera depending on Device you use Surface or Laptop. Now if I select a FirstItem in Combobox i want to change my camera to FrontCamera and set that value and if I select a SecondItem in Combobox  I want to change from FrontCamer and set the BackCamera value.

Comment: In other words var frontCamera = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front); is not returning the object from allVideoDevices based on the condition in the linq query?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is true and when i select this Camera in the Combobox List the value its not set or it's not obtain. You have also a combobox code above the Initalization (); Function and also the event combobx handler i cant understend how its done...

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with MobileEmulator version 10240, the following image shows what I get:
[image]

By my side, if you select the item "SocCaptureSim RFC", the `SelectedIndex` is 0, and if you select the item "SocCaptureSim FFC", the `SelectedIndex` is 1.

But according to your code of `SettingsCamera_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)` method, when I select the item "SocCaptureSim FFC", nothing will happen, because your condition of the `else if`  is `SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 1 && SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 2 && SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 3`, a `ComboBox` doesn't support mutil-selection.

So maybe what you want is `else if (SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 1 || SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 2 || SettingsCamera.SelectedIndex == 3)`.

There are two other problems in your code, `DeviceInformation device = FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel);` in the `InitializeCameraAsync()` method, although you didn't post the code of `FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)` method, according to the left code, I think you pass the wrong parameter here.

And in the `InitializeCameraAsync()` method, I can understand that you want to find all the camera device and add the device to the list of `ComboBox`, but when you select index 0,

```
if (allVideoDevices.Count == 0)
{
    SettingsCamera.Items.Add(frontCamera.Name);
}
```

This code make no sense here, if `allVideoDevices.Count == 0`, this `var frontCamera = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);` will cause an null pointer error at first.

Since I didn't see any of your code for opening a camera to take photos or record, you can refer to the official [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit), see how to get a camera to work.

Comment: Thanx for explaining.My Point is how to change it through Combobox because I managed to open a camera and record it, but my point ist I don't know how to switch cameras through combobox and what should i place in this code instead of-> if (allVideoDevices.Count == 0)
{
    SettingsCamera.Items.Add(frontCamera.Name);
}

Comment: @user2478825, I only pointed out where you are getting wrong with, because there are other situations you will need to consider for recording vedio, for example, the orientation of the camera. The code could be a little complex here, so instead of giving you code directly, I just provided you a official sample for this, please have a look at this sample. It's not a difficult thing to switch camera using `ComboBox`, for example,  finding the back camera: `var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);`